Is there a way to check what the cost of a complex day's travel in London will be?
TfL offers a Single Fare Finder app.
But AFAICT it doesn't have any way of calculating "if I do this sequence of tube, bus, overground, etc. journeys, at these times, on this day of the week ... what will the total cost for that day be?"
Is there a way to calculate that (not manually)

Note that fares on TfL are capped per day.

@mdewey A explanation of that capping and what the capped amount is would make for a good answer.

@PeterM unfortunately the system is complex but perhaps the link will help the OP https://tfl.gov.uk/fares/find-fares/tube-and-rail-fares/pay-as-you-go-caps and then follow more links given there. I am not completely sure whether the OP is looking for a daily cap or a weekly one

In general, no. This rules for determining caps are complex and have a lot of weird edge cases. (For example, the cap varies depending on whether you took a bus during peak hours, but only if you take another mode of transport that day which has peak pricing, even if the other mode was taken off peak)

Additionally, there is out of station transfer pricing, where the time between journeys, the order of stations visited, the form of ticket used, and in some cases which ticket gates you enter/leave from matter. On a case by case basis. And those can be created on a temporary manner as well. (See https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/publications-and-reports/out-of-station-interchanges)

For a rough estimate, going through the single fare finder for each journey and adding them up, And then taking the set of zones, peak/off-peak, and modes, and looking up that cap, and taking the lower of those two values, will give you something that is likely to be the cost in most cases.

(At one point I attempted to build such an app as part of an event, and these are some of the issues I encountered)

Try this: https://tfl.gov.uk/fares/find-fares/tube-and-rail-fares/caps-and-travelcard-prices

Is this question even about caps?

@Relaxed caps are certainly a necessary part of any process that's going to get a correct answer.

I think most of the information has been provided already, in comments, but someone should draw it all together.  You propose to do a day's multi-modal travel in London.  You don't say exactly where, nor when, nor how you're paying.  You want to know what it'll cost.
As long as you're visiting zone 1 at some point, and not going outside the exterior boundary of zone 6, the definitive way to cap your expenditure is to find a manned ticket office and buy a one-day Anytime Z1-6 Travelcard, which will cost you £22.60.  I don't say that's the cheapest, but the cap is absolute: if you try to do a journey that's not included in the card, you won't be able to board the vehicle (tram, bus) or leave via the ticket barriers (tube, train; see footnote 1).
Apparently, it's even cheaper if you pay by contactless, for which the daily cap is £15.60.  The danger is that if you (accidentally) leave those zones, you'll get charged more.
If you're travelling at a weekend, or weekday after 0930, or you take in fewer zones than 1-6 inclusive, the prices may be lower, but that makes no difference to the upper bound.
(footnote 1) the practical upshot of this is you can just turn round, go back to the other platform, and reverse your journey until you're back inside the validity zone.  Theoretically, if you run into a ticket inspector during your excursion from the validity zone, you're in trouble.  This is, in my experience, unlikely.

The cap varies based on the zones visited. For zones 1-2 for instance the cap is £8.50 (while the relevant Travelcard is £15.90).

See "If... you take in fewer zones than 1-6 inclusive, the prices may be lower" above.  But yes, you're right (not least because there is no Z12 travelcard; they start with Z1-4).  My underlying point, however, is that with the cap, you risk a journey that you didn't understand was going to raise you to a different cap level causing you to breach your budget.  With a paper Travelcard, this is not possible; you simply can't do the offending journey.

Or rather you can do it and have a problem at the exit gate... Not sure this is really a sound strategy if you start travelling without knowing the zones you're travelling to.

Completely agree.  But the OP seems more keen to have an absolute cap than the ability to have a soft cap that (s)he can either deliberately or accidentally violate.  If an absolute cap is wanted, a Travelcard is the best way to go.  If the cheapest option is wanted, you're absolutely right that contactless/PAYG is best (though I'm not sure it's always simpler, see eg the pink card reader issue).  But the OP can choose the strategy that best suits his/her needs.

" The danger is that if you (accidentally) leave those zones, you'll get charged more." the bigger danger is that the system misinterprets your travel and you end up with "incomplete journeys" which are outside the cap.

@PeterGreen something else that can't happen with a Travelcard.

In the case you are using contactless or Oyster Pay as you go (which you should, it’s cheaper and simpler):

Use the single fare finder for each trip and add the relevant fares.
Check the zones you will travel through. Then look up the relevant daily caps. For instance if you stay within zones 1-2 (where the vast majority of tourists stay, other than going from/to airports), the daily cap is £8.50.
You will pay the lowest of the two.

If you use only bus and tram the cap is lower at £5.25, whatever the zones travelled through.
If you stay several days, there’s also a weekly cap which can kick in (e.g. £42.70 for zones 1-2, but it works on a Monday-to-Sunday basis only).
Notes:

Always use the same card to touch in or out, otherwise it can’t recognise you and apply the cap.
Always touch in and out for tube or rail journeys.
While it’s unlikely for a tourist, if you travel from one zone with a number higher than 1 to a zone with a number higher than 1 "on the other side" of central London, it’s cheaper to avoid zone 1, but you must use the pink readers available on some platforms for the system to recognise that you did so.

For some combinations of zones there can be different caps of peak and off-peak. The rules are a tad complex, see here for details.

Travelling between "zones higher than 1" only needs pink readers if you the most natural route would travel through zone 1 in the process, ie between zones >1 on opposite sides of London.  Going from Z2 to Z3 is a one-stop journey on most lines and doesn't need anything special.

@user1908704 Indeed, I had meant to restrict that to travel between opposite sides. Fixed. Thanks! (your comment is still more specific so you may want to keep it)

Are you planning to use the system as a normal traveller, travelling from place to place via reasonable routes and spending some time in each place before travelling to the next one? Or are you coming to London specifically to ride around on the train/tube/DLR all day?
In the former case, I would generally suggest using oyster or contactless pay as you go and work on the assumption that you will pay the daily cap for the zones you use. If you don't travel much on a given day then you may pay less, but the cap is a reasonable value to use for budgeting.
In the latter case I would recommend not using oyster/contactless pay as you go and getting a travelcard instead (either a day travelcard on paper, or a weekly one on oyster). The problem is that "incomplete journeys" are not included in the caps. There are a number of issues that normal travellers are unlikely to run in to but become far more likely if you start riding trains for the sake of riding trains that can lead to incomplete journeys being logged.

"Continuation entry" and/or "continuation exit" readers. These are intended to deal with cases where people didn't match their touches properly at interchanges but they can also cause the system to become confused about whether a journey is in progress or not.
"maximum journey times", TFL sets a limit on how long journeys are allowed to take. If you go over this limit you can end up with the touch-in and touch-out being taken as two incomplete journeys.
"out of station interchanges", these are normally a good thing for the customer allowing segments of a journey to be joined together even if the station layout requires you to leave and reenter the ticketed area. But they can lead to journeys being joined up that were intended to be seperate (which in turn can lead to breaches of the maixmum journey times).

Normally you can call TfL and get them to fix incomplete journeys, but a recent cyberattack has been causing them problems in this regard.
